# Panel dataset with not consistent categorical variables across time - mapping

Tags: r, categorical-data, panel-data, plm

I am looking for any resources (journals papers, books, ...) which are connected with handling not consistent categorical variables across time in a panel dataset.
Might you already hear about this topic.
In many projects where dataset contains a categorical variable one of the biggest obstacle is that
the data provider during internal processes was changing an encoding of such variable during a time.
Thus some categories were grouped and other were separated or a new one is added or an old one is removed.
The main objective is to merge a few surveys published by some data provider over the years.
An example of handling such problem is done in this R package:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cat2cat/index.html

Comment: [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out). (Also, welcome to CV, polkas!)

Comment: Hey, could you be more specific. Thanks

Comment: Not sure how I could improve this question. Adding an example from cat2cat package will be helpful?

Comment: My point is that inconsistent and incommensurate measures made at different points in time will almost certainly produce unusable and unreliable results.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, The most often attitude about such scenerio is to abandon such variables. I feel this should not be a 0-1 decision. The distortion in the encoding could be in different magnitude. I have the feeling that the properly created mapping/transition table (often provided by the dataset maintainers) might give possibility to retrieve a significant amount of information for some variable. The example is difference in disease classification icd 10 vs icd 11.

Comment: That makes sense. I think if you provide much more exact details to the question, you may attract answer-level attention.